# Flutter: How can I hide internacionalization class from getx import

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using getx as a state management in my protect and I also I am using `easy_localization`.

Now I need to use both of them in one page but `tr()` is inside `get/get_utils/src/extensions/internacionalization.dart`and I can't use both of these packages with together.

Now I want to `hide` this `internacionalization` from getx import but I got error :

```
import 'package:get/get.dart' hide internacionalization;

The library 'package:get/get.dart' doesn't export a member with the hidden name 'internacionalization'.
```

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can use the `as` keyword instead: `import 'package:get/get.dart' as get`

Comment: No It's not working. I tried

Comment: `import 'package:get/get.dart' hide Trans`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart' hide Trans
```